# Moltin API : Get a list of products where is_variation:false

Tags: javascript, moltin

I read the documentation of Moltin but i don't find the answer.
I use Moltin and i try to get a list of products BUT only products has the parameters is_variation:false.
I try with

```
moltin.Product.Search({is_variation:false},function(){...});
```

and with

```
moltin.Product.List({is_variation:false},function(){...});
```

I don't find the solution.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible because `is_variation` isn't a first class property of an object, rather the product is decorated with it in order to help you understand it.

However, you can change your [store setting](https://docs.moltin.com/settings) to not return variations using the `return_variations` property which in effect gives you the same desired effect, but if you're switching between showing variants and not it means some overhead to call that endpoint first.